# why are some files I created shown as symbolic links?

Tags: files

I just looked at the contents of a directory and noticed some files are showing as symbolic links:

```
% ls -l
-rw-r--r--@  1 pglatz  staff  973 Mar 17 15:53 README.md
drwxr-xr-x   3 pglatz  staff   96 Mar 22 17:33 css
-rw-r--r--@  1 pglatz  staff  228 Apr  3 12:10 node_usage.info.yml
-rw-r--r--   1 pglatz  staff  498 Mar 17 16:40 node_usage.install
-rw-r--r--   1 pglatz  staff   74 Mar 20 13:40 node_usage.libraries.yml
-rw-r--r--   1 pglatz  staff  135 Nov 15 09:38 node_usage.links.menu.yml
```

I'm about to release these as contributed Drupal module, and am not sure what would happen if I commit these to git. And I'm not sure why some are symbolic links. Can I fix them to not be symbolic links, or is this really an issue?

Comment: The `@` after file mode bits does not indicate a symbolic link - see [File Permissions mode ending in @ or +](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92071/file-permissions-mode-ending-in-or)

Comment: For the sake of completeness: Symbolic links have an `l` in the first position and a `->` to where they point: `lrwxrwxrwx user group foo -> bar`

Comment: Ah, thanks. Looks like it's not a problem.